# How would I convert "01010000" in ANSI to create an 8 bit long binary file?

Tags: python, binary

Say I have a notepad file that stores the text "01010000". In binary this is 64 bits long. I want to convert this text to a binary file where it is 8 bits long - "01010000". How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: convert it to bytes like object and write it to a file opened in binary mode- `wb`.

Comment: I tried searching Google but they always think I mean 8 bytes to become 64 bytes, not 1 byte.